# Reusing Key names (e.g. for arrays) in PHP

Tags: php

I'd like to use a variable or constant or something to reuse my key names for arrays to ensure that I don't have a typo inside my script.

Bad example, where I have to retype the keyname:

```
$var = array['keyName'];
$var2 = array['keyName'];
```

Now, if I change the key name I have to check all the places and replace it where necessary.
My current solution is something like this:

```
$key = 'keyName';

$access = array[$key];

function foo($inputArray) {

// Necessary global, to access $key
global $key;

$var = $inputArray[$key];
}
```

But this seems kind of wrong. What would be the best way to reuse key names, while ensuring that my IDE detects all uses? I know about define(string, string), but I had problems in some cases because it didn't resolve them all the time.

This example shows where constants are not working for me:

```
define('requestParameterName', 'requestParam');
function checkGuess() {
    $currentGuess = strtoupper($_REQUEST['requestParameterName'] . " further concatenation");
    echo $currentGuess;
}
```

In the previous example, "requestParameterName" is the valid parameter name, and not "requestParam" as I would like it to be.

Comment: So why don't you use a [constant](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php)?

Comment: "I had problems in some cases because it didn't resolve them all the time." - post a minimal example.

Comment: Tbh I don't understand your motivation. If they have information that is connected, why not use `$keyName = array(..)`? If not, why force the same naming if they actually mean something else (and not use more fitting names)?

Comment: I added a minimum example where constants don't work for me.

As for my motivation, my example above doesn't really show that I'm reusing the parameter names for the same things, but in reality I do it a lot (e.g. accessing session parameters etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the example you just posted drop the `''` in `$_REQUEST['requestParameterName']`. Make it just `$_REQUEST[requestParameterName]`. I would use all uppercase letters in constants though, just to make it easier to read.

Comment: thanks a lot, this seems to work. Is there a general rule I can apply here? Can I always drop the ''?

Comment: You never use them when accessing something you set in a [define](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php).

Comment: Strings are always quoted when you use them, constants are only quoted when you define them, and ___never___ when you use them.... that's how PHP knows it's a constant and not a string